# 画像の周囲に、灰色の枠が表示されてしまう。

Tags: monaca, 画像

下のようなボタンの素材（透明部分はトリミングしています）を
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このように表示したいのですが
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下のように周囲に灰色の枠が表示されてしまいます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この灰色部分を消すことは可能でしょうか？

現状以下のように、テンプレートの「Train Catalog」を書き換え
記述しています。

```
<div data-role="page" id="detail-page"class="story-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <img src="images/story_top.png" alt="" width="100%"> 
       <a href="list.html" ><img src="images/returnbutton.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <img src="" alt="" id="story-image" width="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQueryMobileを使用しているようですので、英語になりますが、下記Stackoverflowが参考になりますよ。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185862/custom-header-buttons-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score -1):

CSSを操作することでボタンの背景を透明にすることが可能です。下記のコードを試してみてください。同じく、Monacaのサンプルで作りました。

```
<!-- TOP Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="TopPage">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Monaca Memo</h1>
        <a href="#AddPage" class="ui-btn-right" style="background: transparent !important;" ><img src=".hoge.png"/></a>
    </header>
</div>
```